# Microsoft Account SignIn button cannot be clickable (Java Selenium Excel)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, excel

[image]This is my code

```
public void AccessLogin() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    WebElement oauth = driver.findElement(oAuth);
    oauth.click();
    driver.get("https://login.microsoftonline.com/9b681ea3-df3f-4111-b6aa-88fe01ce2168/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ee37b577-2953-4322-bc20-0219dc73bc04&scope=email%20offline_access%20openid%20profile%20User.Read.All%20Group.Read.All&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fhpr-frontend-v1-test.h2software.nl%2Flogin&client-request-id=07bc035c-321c-4d40-9f5e-12d9b9b585fd&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.38.3&client_info=1&code_challenge=bgf5HAV3a1gPr-frqCVl4UR80uQVakEb7qwM0pywJgQ&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=25e5b77b-078e-4de4-bd68-2fc72184aa8c&state=eyJpZCI6IjhhNDhjNTRlLTk3MjUtNDcwZi1hZjNjLWJiNzdjNWU5MDg2OCIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoicG9wdXAifX0%3D");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement Username = driver.findElement(username);
    
    WebElement Password = driver.findElement(password);
    
    //WebElement SignIn = driver.findElement(btSignIn);
  
    excelUtils.setExcelFile(excelFilePath, "Sheet1");

    for (int i = 1; i <= excelUtils.getRowCountInSheet(); i++) {
    if (excelUtils.getRowCountInSheet() >= i) {
        String usernameValue = excelUtils.getCellData(i, 0);
        String passwordValue = excelUtils.getCellData(i, 1);
        
        Username.sendKeys(usernameValue);
        Password.sendKeys(passwordValue);
        WebElement SignIn = driver.findElement(btSignIn);
        SignIn.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        
    }else {
        System.out.println("Row " + i + " does not exist in the Excel sheet.");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! It would be helpful if you added more than just code to your question. What errors are you getting? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you, I am not getting any errors in the Eclipse IDE, the test getting passed, but SignIn doesn't work. when I enter username and password using Excel, and when I click the SigIn button the test getting closes.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved.

By btSignIn = By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign in']"); - **we have to mention the value here. it is the best option.**

public void AccessLogin() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

```
    WebElement oauth = driver.findElement(oAuth);
    oauth.click();
    driver.get("the website url");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    Element(oAuth).click();

    WebElement Username = driver.findElement(username);

    WebElement Password = driver.findElement(password);

    excelUtils.setExcelFile(excelFilePath, "Sheet1");

    for (int i = 1; i <= excelUtils.getRowCountInSheet(); i++) {
        if (excelUtils.getRowCountInSheet() >= i) {
            String usernameValue = excelUtils.getCellData(i, 0);
            String passwordValue = excelUtils.getCellData(i, 1);

            Username.sendKeys(usernameValue);
            driver.findElement(btNext).click();
            Password.sendKeys(passwordValue);
            driver.findElement(btSignIn).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(btYes).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            // WebElement SignIn = driver.findElement(btSignIn);
            // SignIn.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Row " + i + " does not exist in the Excel sheet.");
        }
    }

}

public void OAuthLogin() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(oAuth).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

}
```